# Finding the average of non-zero values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the fastest way to find the average of non-zero "table" values in this python dictionary:

```
d = {"a":{"pen":12,"table":23},"b":{"pen":12,"table":0},"c":{"pen":16,"table":54}}
```

I think of:

```
count = sum(1 for inner_dict in d if d[inner_dict]["table"] > 0)
total = sum([d[inner_dict]["table"] for inner_dict in d if d[inner_dict]["table"] > 0])
average = total/count
```

the result should be (23+54)/2 = 38

Comment: That looks right. What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Nothing, I just wanted to know if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Make sure "count" is not 0.

Comment: You're iterating over `d` twice, so you can definitely be more efficient.

Comment: "fastest" is always arbitrary -- It depends on too many factors (platform, python version, etc.).  There's nothing wrong with how you've written it and it'll likely perform comparable to anything else that you cook can cook up using vanilla python :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
filtered = [d[i]["table"] for i in d if d[i]["table"]<>0]
avg = sum(filtered)/len(filtered)
```

don't actually need <>0 though

Comment: Who's upvoting an answer with `<>` in it?  ;-)

Comment: Personally, I use a rating system that scales with user rep.  ...btw, with your rep, a single character out of place will merit a downvote ;-)

Comment: @Gerrat -- Noted.  I'll be sure to pay attention to spell check.

Answer (score 3):

Because you asked for the *fastest*, here are some timings. Note that I'm using IPython and Python 3.3 on Windows 8, running an i7-3770. Also, on a side note, you shouldn't be using `/` for division on Python 2.x, as it does integer division. Use `float(a)/b` instead, or add a `from __future__ import division` to the top of your file.

```
d = {"a": {"pen": 12, "table": 23}, 
     "b": {"pen": 12, "table": 0},
     "c": {"pen": 16, "table": 54}}

def method0():  # Your method
    count = sum(1 for inner_dict in d if d[inner_dict]["table"] > 0)
    total = sum([d[inner_dict]["table"] for inner_dict in d if d[inner_dict]["table"] > 0])
    average = total/count

def method1():
    count = 0
    total = 0
    for a in d.values():
        val = a['table']
        if val > 0:
            count += 1
            total += val
    average = total/ count

def method2():  # user3684792's/Padraic Cunningham's method
    filtered = [d[i]["table"] for i in d if d[i]["table"] > 0]
    average = sum(filtered)/len(filtered)   

# from functools import reduce  # If using Python 3
def method3():  # Sylvain Leroux's method
    n, s = reduce(lambda acc,v: (acc[0]+1,acc[1]+v["table"]) if v["table"] else acc,
                  d.values(),
                  (0, 0))
    average = s/n


%timeit method0()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 23.9 us per loop

%timeit method1()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 756 ns per loop

%timeit method2()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 22.5 us per loop

%timeit method3()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 us per loop
```

Tentative conclusion: Using a for loop and simple addition (`method1`) is a lot faster than any of the list comprehension methods for this example.

This is pretty much what you would expect. Note that method 1 and 3 only iterate through the data once, collecting it all as they go. Methods 0 and 2 iterate through more, as they take one pass to filter out the entries they want then another pass to sum them up.

Comment: +1 for answering "what's fastest?" with "let's run it and see!" You know...collecting actual data.

Comment: this is wrong. method 0 should have count as len not sum

Comment: so, using for loop is the fastest method?

Comment: Why are you looping on `d.items()` instead of `d.values()`, since you don’t need each key?

Comment: @bfontaine Good point, I modified it (and the timing) to use `values`. Slight speedup.

Comment: what are you timing this on?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham IPython, Python 3.3, Windows 8, i7-3770.

Comment: @Roger: Throw in Sylvain's method for kicks

Comment: takes `870 ns ` to run the same code on my laptop, I think your computer is broken ;)

Comment: Your timings are crazy, nowhere near accurate

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you want to run them on your setup I'd love to see any discrepancies. That's why I posted the code.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating only *once*:

```
n, s = reduce(lambda acc,v: (acc[0]+1,acc[1]+v["table"]) if v["table"] else acc,
              d.values(),
              (0.,0.))
print n, s, s/n
```

Producing:

```
2.0 77.0 38.5
```

Comment: I think you meant `s/n`, not `n/s`.

Comment: @bfontaine Thnak you. Fixed. Too late here. Sleep ;)

Comment: I know, I’m in the same country :) Anyway, great answer, I was trying to do the same but you were faster. You can even shorten the answer to 87 chars: `t='table';n,s=reduce(lambda(x,y),v:(x+1,y+v[t])if v[t]else(x,y),d.values(),(0.,0.));s/n`.

Comment: @bfontaine Unfortunately, using `reduce` is _much_ slower than expected... The "basic" `method1` by Roger Fan above is the clear winner (almost twice as fist as this version!) I bet this is because of the function call. Damn it!

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Read [this](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) for Guido's take on optimization. A for loop vs. reduce example is near the beginning. You're exactly right, from the link: "function call overhead in Python is bigger than for loop overhead."

Comment: @RogerFan Interesting, thank you for posting this link.